Mechanical keyboard without lighting effects
I threw my old Logitech (mechanical) keyboard  to replace it with a new G915.  To my horror, it permanently plays the Xmas light effect.  I don't need this distraction.  From Logitech's own pages, it can't be removed.
Looking for a new keyboard (in Australia)

Mechanical keyboard
Prefer corded (I have enough wireless things around me that make a BT keyboard slow)
If backlit at all, just a steady calm colour (not a rainbow or Xmas effect)
Not too clicky (I do have o-rings that I purchased to silence a keybord - they may actually work)
Not too fussed about the price
Don't really want to wait weeks for it to arrive

I know I can Google to find a such keyboard.  However I need to know that unlike the Logitech one, I can turn off the silly effects, before I buy it.

I found a few, but ended up buying this one from mwave

Cherry MX 3.0S NBL White Mechanical Gaming Keyboard

Cherry MX Red Switches
RGB Lighting: No
Layout: US-International
Colour: White
Keycap: Lasered
Full N-Key Rollover
Anti-Ghosting Setup
WIN-Key Lockout
Detachable Cable
Four Round Rubber Feet
G80-3870LYAEU-0

